# Can HTTPS connections be hijacked with a man-in-the-middle attack?

Tags: security, browser, encryption, https, cryptography

I'm using gmail from work, but I need to enter a password for a proxy when accesing the first web page.  The password is asked from inside the browser.  I receive a certificate from the proxy which I must accept in order to make the Internet connection work.

Can my HTTPS connection, between gmail and browser, be tracked in this situation?

Comment: Superuser might be a better forum for this question though I think it is of interest to anyone developing https sites. And just to mention prefixing a question "Debate:" is probably a sure fire way of getting it closed as subjective and argumentative!

Comment: @Martin Smith  He is going to get a better answer from a programmer.

Comment: Does the proxy server present you a fake certificate for gmail.com that you are forced to accept? I think you are accepting a SSL certificate for the proxy server, and not for the end website you are visiting. Can you confirm this?

Comment: [Don't](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46035/should-i-remove-tags-that-dont-contribute-to-categorizing-the-question/46037#46037) [tag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43879/anti-tags-valid-use-or-not) [not-programming-related.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10216/can-we-disallow-the-use-of-belongs-on-xxxxxxx-and-not-programming-related-tag/10222#10222) @corey

Comment: When do you receive the certificate from the proxy? Only on the first connection where you login to the proxy? Otherwise it's hijacking your Gmail TLS session... And what do you mean by "tracked"? The proxy can only fingerprint you and know your IP address and what you are connecting to as long as it's not hijacking your TLS session. None of these answers are valid because you didn't provide a question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/httpsdecryption.asp) describes it like this:

> Q: The HTTPS protocol was designed to prevent traffic viewing and tampering.  Given that, how can Fiddler2 debug HTTPS traffic?
>
> A: Fiddler2 relies on a "man-in-the-middle" approach to HTTPS interception.  To your web browser, Fiddler2 claims to be the secure web server, and to the web server, Fiddler2 mimics the web browser.  In order to pretend to be the web server, Fiddler2 dynamically generates a HTTPS certificate.
>
> Fiddler's certificate is not trusted by your web browser (since Fiddler is not a Trusted Root Certification authority), and hence while Fiddler2 is intercepting your traffic, you'll see a HTTPS error message in your browser, like so:

Comment: +1. And of course if you accept the fiddler certificate then you won't see the HTTPS error message.

Comment: Fiddler causes the browser to throw an error and thats the point of https.  However  **sslstrip** can bypass https without throwing an error.  You should read my post.

Comment: @Rook - Totally agree with you. I spent a lot of time trying to suppress the untrusted ssl certificate warning using paros proxy and mitm proxy, but finally achieved it only using sslstrip.

Answer (score 11):

tracked?  Well even though https encrypts the traffic you still know the ip address of both parties (gmail and the browser).  HTTPS doesn't solve this problem,  but a different blend of crypto has created [The Onion Router(TOR)](http://www.torproject.org/) which does make impossible to locate both servers and clients.

Under "normal" conditions when an attacker is trying to MITM HTTPS your browser should throw a certificate error.  This is the whole point of SSL backed by a PKI.   **HOWEVER**  in 2009 Moxie Marlenspike gave a killer Blackhat talk in which he was able to MITM HTTPS without warning.  His tools is called [SSLStrip](http://www.thoughtcrime.org/software/sslstrip/),  and I highly recommend watching that video.

A good solution to SSLStrip was developed by Google.  Its called [STS](http://ha.ckers.org/blog/20100413/chrome-fixes-sts-privacy-issue/),  and you should enable this on **all** of your web applications.   Currently sts is only supported by Chrome, but Firefox is working on their supporting this feature.  Eventually all browsers *should* support it.

Comment: Rook +1 for SSLStrip. It'd work 99% of the times, but if the user *directly* enters https:// in the browser, it won't work. SSLStrip only works if the first request to the server is over http.

Answer (score 2):

Yes they can. You can see this for yourself by downloading Fiddler and using it to decrypt https traffic. Fiddler issues its own certificate and acts a man in the middle. You would need to view the certificate in your browser to see whether it is actually issued by gmail.

Comment: This doesnt proof that you can perform a man in the middle on https, perhaps fiddler can do this because it resides inside the browser. In that case it is no longer called a man-in-the-middle attack but a man-in-the-browser attack (no kidding).
If fiddler does not depend on residing in the browser, can you please provide more details on how this can be done? and how fidler does this

Comment: @Henri - See my comment to your answer.

Comment: Yes,  but fidderl's attack throws a warning so Https is doing its job.  sslstrip can bypass this warning all together.

Comment: @The Rook  It won't throw a warning for the OP as he has already accepted the certificate.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the renegotiation is a weak spot in the TSLv1 (see [*TLS renegotiation attack. More bad news for SSL*](http://www.cupfighter.net/index.php/2009/11/tls-renegotiation-attack/)).

Comment: It is, but it is not really relevant here.

Comment: +1 much cooler attack than fiddler.   sslstrip kicks ass!  I saw his talk when I was at blackhat last year.

Comment: @Henri   you need to see Moxie Marlenspike's talk and then delete your comment.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by other answers (read also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073166/capturing-https-traffic-in-the-clear)) for this to work really "in the middle" (i.e. excluding the cases in which the capturing occurs at one of the end-points, inside the browser or inside the web server), some kind of proxy must be set, who speaks to your browser and to the server, pretending to both to be the other side. But your browser (and ssl) is smart enough to realize that the certificate that the proxy sends you ("saying: I am gmail") is illegal, i.e. is not signed by a trusted Root Certification authority. Then, this will only work if the user explicitly accepts that untrusted certificate, or if the CA used by the proxy was inserted into the trusted CA registry in his browser.

In summary, if the user is using a clean/trusted browser installation, and if he refuses certificates issued by untrusted authorities, an man "in the middle" cannot decrypt an https communication.

Comment: From the question: "I receive from the proxy a certificate which I must accept in order to make the Internet connection work."

Answer (score -1):

It cannot be tracked between the gmail webserver and your pc, but once it is inside the pc, it can be tracked. I dont understand how two people claim that https can be tracked with mitm since the whole purpose of https is to prevent such attacks.

The point is that all HTTP level messages are encrypted, and mac-ed. Due to the certificate trust chain, you cannot fake a certificate, so it should not be possible to perform a man in the middle.

The ones who claim it is possible, can you please give details about how and why it is possible and how the existing countermeasures are circumvented?

Comment: The OP says "I receive from the proxy a certificate which I must accept in order to make the Internet connection work." I presume that browser -> proxy is https encrypted using that certificate. *Not* gmail's. It is then decrypted at the proxy and re encrypted when doing the https request to gmail. It should be possible to see this though by clicking the padlock icon and viewing the certificate.