# See WCF http data from Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf, visual-studio

I am implementing the client-side of a ms webservice and i would like to see the exact http call that is made. i.e. all the parameters and how they are encoded.

I tried sniffing it with wireshark, but since it seems it is done via https i can see the data.

I am running this client straight out of visual studio. is there a way to see the data there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Teletic Fiddler is great tool to debug any http communication. http://www.telerik.com/fiddler. I can show request and response information in raw views, xml, JSON etc

It can even inspect https traffic. Follow [this guide](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/configure-fiddler/tasks/decrypthttps/).

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073166/capturing-https-traffic-in-the-clear).